# Possible to create a login using AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to use AMPscript to create a password protected area within the ET app? If so, where are some resources we could use to build this?

Comment: What part of the ET app?  Protect it from whom? Is there anything currently you are trying, or is this just a feasibility question?

Comment: It's in the Email portion of the IMH, and it's for Partner Resources, so only Partners can view materials and have access to documents. This is just a feasibility question.

Comment: @RobWeis -- yes, this is an E2.0 account. We need the ability to create a page that's protected from the general public, but if they type in a certain username/password, they would be able to access the protected content.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an Enterprise 2.0 account? Enterprise 2 comes with built in permissions that allow you to customize view/edit/delete/etc. permissions of the app. Here is an example of what you can do with Portfolio:

[image: Portfolio-Permissions]

Comment: @aaron bushnell - what content are you trying to protect?